# How to do fuzzy matching against an array in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have an array that looks like:

```
* def test = [abc_4512_412.csv, asdfc_4d32_412.csv, asdfc_4d4_412.csv]
```

I need to verify that my partial String match at least 1 object in the array

```
* match test contains "abc_"+ "4512" + "#regex (?i).*"
```

This is not working and not finding any match even though it is there

Answer (score 0):

The `#regex` macro has to match the whole value:

```
* def response = ['abc_4512_412.csv', 'asdfc_4d32_412.csv', 'asdfc_4d4_412.csv']
* match response contains '#regex abc_4512_[0-9]+.*'
```

Note that "self validations" plus JavaScript may be easier: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#self-validation-expressions

```
* match response contains "#? _.includes('412.csv')"
```